# Ajax Post, jQuery not working on the ResponseData result page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Post Form in wich i use to Search results.

```
<form  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="byMonthYear">
            <label><h2>Search Colection by Month and Year:</h2></label>
            <select name="month">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year">
                <?php 
                        $get_year = date('Y') + 1;
                    for($i = $get_year;$i >= 2013;$i--){
                        echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Search"  onclick="return search_buss_byMonthYear()">
        </form>
```

On click i call AJAX to get the results search_buss_byMonthYear();

```
function search_buss_byMonthYear(){
    $('#loading').show();
    var month = document.forms['byMonthYear']['month'].value;
    var year = document.forms['byMonthYear']['year'].value;
    var dataString = 'month='+ month + '&year=' + year;
    if(month == '')
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='alert_error'>You must fill all fields! <br></div>";
    }else{
      $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "inc/byMonthYear.php",
            data: dataString,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = responseData;
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<div class='alert_error'>Your action had errors! <br></div>";
            }
        });
  }
```

}

on the File byMonthYear.php i have the php script to get the results, and is working very good, BUT i want to add some additional javascript action on that page byMonthYear.php.. But its not responding the jQuery there! 
I put just alert("hello"); to test is but its not responding !!
Any idea how to bind the jQuery to work in this conditions !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
I just added this on success and javascript responds.

```
  success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 $('#results').html( responseData );
            },
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript you added does not work in byMonthYear.php. You are trying to call a php webpage by ajax and that page will be executed server side not client side.

You can try to return the Javascript code by `echo` and a flag. If that flag is set then display the `Alert()`. Use JSON to send data.

Guess you understood.

Comment: i tryed to send data with JSON, but no succesed to get javascript respond on that page :(

Answer (score 0):

i am not a hundred percent sure but try including your javascript file to the new php page
it souds like a problem i had a wile back where i was using ajax to call load a page but the javascript did not work so i had to include them again like so

```
<head>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjava.js"></script>
</head>
```